# Some android apps not working on WiFi, but working on mobile data

Tags: networking, wi-fi, router

I've had a strange scenario these days.

**While on WiFi connection**, whenever I tried accessing certain apps from my android device, they would be **stuck on the loading screen forever**. Other apps were working fine, there were only few apps with this problem, that were not related (ex: **Skype and some food delivery apps**)

Then, **after switching to mobile data, those apps were working fine**. Switching back to wifi, the apps were stuck again at loading.

Then, I found out that **multiple devices connected to this WiFi network were encountering the same problem** with the same apps. Then, I knew the problem was with my network. **I restarted the router and then everything worked fine again.**

My question is: **what could be the reason this happened?** The router was untouched for at least half an year, and this problem appeared only last few days. Could it be that those apps were asking for location and the WiFi couldn't provide it properly or something happened to the network by a malicious encounter?

Comment: Does the router advertise itself as a DNS server/resolver via DHCP?

Comment: I am not sure, I do not have the box or any info about the model unfortunately

Comment: I'm not sure why this was migrated to here. Apps don't need to connect to WiFi to locate itself (further reading: [Wi-Fi positioning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system)). This looks like an issue with the router, not Android.

Comment: I have the same issue with galaxy s23, did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Yes, it was in fact, the router. Did a router restart and worked fine after. Not sure why it happened, but it was the router.